# I want to create a relational Database in Django with user_auth table which is created automatically in postgreSQL

Tags: python, django

I want to create a Relational database with auth_user table which is automatically created in django after migrations(database is postgresql). I have created a table with class named order. My models.py looks like this

Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
   # Create your models here.

class order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.IntegerField()
```

now I want to link the user id with table order with user_id. And my views.py looks like this.
views.py

```
def order_Data(request):
    product = request.POST['product']
    price = request.POST['price']


    orders = order(product=product,price=price)


    orders.save()
    messages.info(request,'Data saved')
    return render(request,'home.html')
```

I think I have linked tables properly but in user_id of order table is setting as null and giving me error. I dont know what to do now. Please Help me out (Iam also a learner in Django). Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You didn’t pass the user to the order

```
orders = order(product=product,price=price, user=request.user)
```

Given you have a logged-in user

Comment: That's it???? Is that so simple?? Okay thanks a lot.

Comment: Thank you so much sir.....that worked.....you solved my problem

Comment: Please accept answer to close the question.